# Почему база данных не создалась, хотя был код?

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Использую MS SQL server
Вот код :

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb
USE mydb
```

Но по каким-то не ясным причинам возникает ошибка :

> Сообщение 911, уровень 16, состояние 1, строка 2
>   База данных "mydb" не существует. Убедитесь, что ее имя введено правильно.

Почему так происходит, ведь перед второй строкой написан код создания этой самой базы данных

Comment: Если Вы это выполняете из SSMS, то вставьте `GO` между этими строчками.

Comment: Я понимаю, что если что-то эдакое вставить, то оно заработает. Тут дело в другом: почему то что имеется не работает? и почему, чтобы это заработало нужен GO?

Comment: Потому что пакет (batch) компилируется целиком, и в этот момент база ещё не существует. А `GO` - это разделитель пакетов

Comment: ну пусть компилируется, что ему мешает то компилироваться. Компиляция это одно, а исполнение другое. На стадии компиляции ведь еще ничего не происходит .

Comment: Вы передаёте пакет из 2-х команд на сервер. Пакет целиком (обе команды) 1) парсится - синтаксис валидный, Ок, наступает этап 2) биндинг - указанный в use идентификатор БД проверяется на существование, а его нет (т.к. исполнение переданных команд ещё не началось), отбой, ошибка.

Comment: @i-one, то есть  получается так: sql код разделяется на пакеты командой GO. Если в пакете записано обращение к какой-либо сущности, то эта сущность должна быть уже создана

Comment: @i-one, верно так?

Comment: GO - это фича SSMS (и некоторых других приложений), а не языка T-SQL. Т.е. если через какую-то прикладную библиотеку работать с сервером напрямую, то нужно именно две команды отдельно передавать. Сам сервер GO не распарсит. Что касается проверки сущности, то это, по-видимому, зависит и от команды и от сущности, возможно и от других факторов. Например, `CREATE TABLE T(N int); SELECT * FROM T;` сработает в одном пакете. Видимо какие-то проверки делаются до начала выполнения пакета, а какие-то могут откладываться до начала исполнения конкретной инструкции.

Comment: @i-one, благодарю, в общем понял.

Comment: Так. Наврал я вам немного. `USE mydb`, если верить отладчику, сваливается в ошибку ещё на этапе парсинга, если БД не существует.

Answer (score 2):

C помощью запроса

```
USE наименование_базы_данных;
```

вы обращаетесь к уже существующей базе данных, но на данный момент у вас её не существует. База данных создается с помощью запроса

```
CREATE DATABASE наименование_базы_данных;
```

После запроса `CREATE DATABASE` используйте отдельно запрос `USE`.

Так же не забывайте ставить `;` после каждого запроса.

Comment: да как не существует, если на предыдущей строке она создается

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: "После запроса, CREATE DATABASE наименование_базы_данных, используйте отдельно запрос,USE наименование_базы_данных" -  "отдельно"  означает использование конструкции "GO", что SQL Server понимает, как разделитель пакетов, что нужно выполнить один пакет, а затем приступить выполнять второй. В каждом пакете могут быть свои инструкции

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE DATABASE название;
GO

USE название;
GO
```

Просто надо разделить на мелкие запросы.